# Animations crash

Tags: 16.04, animations

I'm trying to breathe some life into an old setup I happen to have lying around by installing Ubuntu onto it, as windows 7 no longer works correctly. I chose 16.04 LTS because its the last version to support 32bit architecture. The installation went all right, and so did the first boot. I come in to the desktop, and click the application menu (Dash, is it called?) and immediately, the display starts spazzing out, I get a whole lot of multicoloured, digital mess. However, CTRL+ALT+F3 still works, and when I run `sudo systemctl restart lightdm`, the console exits, and I'm back at the login screen. I sign in, and I'm immediately back to the craziness. Recovery mode doesn't work at all, I get the colour madness as soon as it boots. How do I fix this? Also, Windows 7 works fine.
Update: I ran a memory check, all good. Windows ran a disk check, nothing. I had a copy of Kubuntu 18.04 already, booted from it, ran the trial run-from-the-disk option, and it went nuts immediately.

Comment: The last release of 32bit (i386) ISOs was 2020-August, and multiple Ubuntu *flavors* provide i386 support via 18.04. Chances are your box is *amd64* anyway as 64-bit came out about ~2000 though yes low-end consumer models continued for some time after that (windows 32 bit was $5 cheaper, and consumers understood $5 far more than 32bit vs 64bit so amd64 boxes were sold usually with 32-bit windows to reduce box price by $5).  Did you check your box meets the hardware requirements https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements which are higher for Ubuntu 16.04 than 18.04 flavor

Comment: Key requirement in the listed page is "*3D Acceleration Capable Videocard with at least 256 MB*" as crashes could be expected if your hardware didn't meet that requirement. As Ubuntu 16.04 LTS reaches EOL in 2021-April, a *flavor* of 18.04 doesn't have a shorter life, in fact it's base will be supported 2 years longer on i386 (even if GUI/desktop may not).

Comment: @guiverc I can confirm this system is 32bit. As for a fix, would an older distro work?

Comment: I'm using Lubuntu 18.04 LTS on a 2005 thinkpad (too old & never was capable of running win vista/7, but happily runs Lubuntu 18.04 LTS). Why would you want an older one?  I don't know how old your boxes were, but I tested the 18.04.5 release August 2020 using boxes as old as from 2003. (FYI:  19.04 was the last that supported i386. but ISOs produced starting in 17.10 were reduced, even though support continued till 19.04). Many of your facts are wrong or you're reading unofficial/3rd party sources.  (*I tested using pentium 4, pentium M etc... what are you using that can run win7 but not*...)